# Why http and not https?

Tags: bug, security

All stackexchange sites use http by default. When i checked to update my email address, that was too sent on http.

[image]

Why stackexchange doesn't use https for at least user data?

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate of the last question. The title may be similar, but the contents of the question is different. Also, the other post is from over 5 years ago.